# How to configure rate-limit with fastify-adapter in nest js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, rate-limiting, fastify, nestjs-fastify

I Just started implementing API's Nest js and I am using Fastify adapter.
I need help to configure Rate limit using FastifyAdapter in Nest JS.

```
async function bootstrap() {
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
        AppModule,
        new FastifyAdapter(),
    );

    const limiter = fastifyRateLimit(fastify(), {
        timeWindow: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
        max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
    }, (err) => {
    });
    app.use(limiter);
    await app.listen(configService.getPort());
}

bootstrap();
```

Please refer to the above code and correct the mistake

Comment: How are you getting `fastify()`?

Comment: I installed using npm

Comment: No, in your code, where your are seeing up the rate limiter, you have `fastify()` but I don't see `fastify` initialized anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

Install:

`npm install fastify-rate-limit --save`

Import (In main.ts):

`import * as fastifyRateLimit from 'fastify-rate-limit';`

Usage:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  // Create our app, bootstrap using fastify
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );

  // Apply rate limiter
  app.register(fastifyRateLimit, {
    max: 25,
    timeWindow: '1 minute'
  });
}
```

Comment: By registering it at the app level it will be active for all routes but how can you change the limits for specific routes? I would like to create a decorator to overwrite the default limits for some routes. Is that the correct approach ?

Comment: @NicolasOste I believe this is not supported for Fastify. I have since moved away from Fastify. While nice in theory, it proved to be incompatible with some features and overall not enough performance increase for the extra headache.