# How do I apply fastify rate limiter to a single route in Nest JS?

Tags: nestjs, rate-limiting, fastify

I am able to apply a rate limiter to my nest app globally using code similar to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376187/how-to-configure-rate-limit-with-fastify-adapter-in-nest-js). On the [fastify rate limiter readme](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-rate-limit), it is shown that you can apply a rate limiter to a specific route via a config property with the rateLimit object with options. Nest's documentation does not explain how to do this; is it possible in the framework or am I out of luck?

Comment: Why not add your code examples instead of sending people off to multiple links?
Your question would be more clearly understood that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no inherent way to add it only to an endpoint, but you could modify the `whitelist` property function to return `true` for all routes except the one(s) you want to rate-limit. It could look something like

```js
app.use(rateLimit({
  whitelist: (req, key) => {
    return !limitProtectedRoutes.includes(req.url);
  }),
}));
```

May need a few more modifications, but the idea is there

Comment: A little hacky but if I really can't do it the "proper" way this looks good to me! Will accept after giving a little time for other answers.

Comment: Yeah, there's no real way to drop down to the fastify instance to register a middleware directly, so this is about as good as you'll get